# Javascript Regex string ends with and only contains one occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a scenario where I need to identitify using javascript regex when a string ends with the string 47368 but not when there's multiple occurrences of 47368. For example I'd expect the following results

```
localhost:47368 => true
localhost:47368/abc => false
localhost:47368/abc/47368 => false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern for this use case ("match this and not that") is

```
 ^ (?! .* non-match) match
```

in your case:

```
^(?!.*47368.).*47368$
```

https://regex101.com/r/riDD2r/1